# Powershell not writing multiple rows to Excel

Tags: excel, powershell, automation

Hopefully someone can assist, I'm new to Powershell and I've tried creating a few scripts to automate some internal processes. I think I've jumped into the deep end however and I just can't get the below to work.

Essentially I'm trying to use WMI to call WMI to retrieve data from computers inside the network.

The script uses a list of hostnames from my C:Drive to run the queries against and output the data (well it should anyway.) Can anyone help please?

```
#Create new Excel workbook and write fields.

$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$excel.visible = $False 
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add() 
$workbook.Worksheets.Add() | Out-Null 
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $False 
$excel.Rows.Item(1).Font.Bold = $true

$Sheet= $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1) 
$Sheet.Name = 'Server Information' 
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,1) = "Manufacturer"
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,2) = "Hostname"
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,3) = "PC Model"
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,4) = "Username"
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,5) = "Serial Number"
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,6) = "OS Architecture"
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,7) = "HDD Model"
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,8) = "Total Disk Size (GB)"
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,9) = "Physical Memory (GB)"

#Import data from text file.
Write-Host "Enter file path for hostnames list..." -ForegroundColor yellow
$computers = (Read-Host 'Insert File Path') 
$computername = Get-Content $computers -ErrorAction "Inquire"

Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Excel workbook generated successfully. Writing data to rows and columns..." -ForegroundColor yellow
Write-Host $computername.count lines of data imported.
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Starting WMI Querying..." -ForegroundColor yellow

#Loop through the Array and add data into the excel file created.

foreach ($computername in $computers) {
    ($Manufacturer,$Model,$User,$SerialNumber,$OSType,$DDModel,$DDSize,$RAMSize) = $computername.split('|')
    $introw = $Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

    $Manufacturer = $cs.Manufacturer
    $Model = $cs.Model
    $User = $cs.UserName
    $SerialNumber = $bios.SerialNumber
    $OSType = $os.Architecture
    $DDModel = $dd.Model
    $DDSize = $dd.Size
    $RAMSize = $cs.PhysicalSize

    (Get-Content C:\nodes.txt) | ForEach-Object {
    $cs = gwmi win32_computersystem | Select-Object Manufacturer,@{Name="PC Model"; Expression = {$cs.Model}},Username,@{Name="Physical Memory (GB)";e={[math]::truncate($_.TotalPhysicalMemory /1GB)}}
    $bios = gwmi win32_bios | Select-Object SerialNumber
    $os = gwmi win32_OperatingSystem | select-object OSArchitecture
    $dd = gwmi win32_DiskDrive | select-object Model,@{Name="Total Disk Size (GB)";e={[math]::truncate($dd.Size /1GB)}}

    $Sheet.cells.item($introw, 1) = $Manufacturer  
    $Sheet.cells.item($introw, 2) = $Model
    $Sheet.cells.item($introw, 3) = $User
    $Sheet.cells.item($introw, 4) = $SerialNumber 
    $Sheet.cells.item($introw, 5) = $OSType 
    $Sheet.cells.item($introw, 6) = $DDModel
    $Sheet.cells.item($introw, 7) = $DDSize
    $Sheet.cells.item($introw, 8) = $RAMSize
    $Sheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

    }
}

#Write and output to Excel file.
$usedRange = $Sheet.UsedRange 
$usedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null 
$workbook.SaveAs("C:\Machine Inventory.xlsx")  
$excel.Quit()

Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Process complete! The data has been exported to C:\Machine Inventory.xlsx" -ForegroundColor yellow
Write-Host ""

Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..." -ForegroundColor yellow
$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the script won't do it, but are you able to just output the data instead of writing it to Excel? If you output to screen does it come out right? If so, a better way to do what you want is to create an array of custom objects, convert that array to a tab delimited CSV, copy it to the clipboard, then paste it to Excel. If your script can output the right info to screen I can help with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You do not increase `$introw` in your foreach-object script block, so you have your script rewrite one single row over and over. Add `$introw+=1` to the end of `(Get-Content C:\nodes.txt) | ForEach-Object {...}` block. Should do.